# Action script adding a background

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

First of all I've just a couple hours experience with Flash and AS3 therefore, I'm sorry if it is a bit easy question.

What I want do to is a simple space war games to learn basics of AS3 and flash. Altough I dont know much things about layers, I think my game should contain two layers, one for background and the second one is for enemies spaceships and our spaceship.

I added a jpeg format file to library to use it as a background. (as you can see from the link :http://prntscr.com/2pe6zb and http://prntscr.com/2pe733 )

And I create a as3 documentFile which is called `Arkaplan.as` and content of it is:

```
package{
    import flash .display.*;
    public class Arkaplan extends MovieClip{
        public function Arkaplan(){
            var hero:backGround =new backGround();
            addChild(hero);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I got an error which says that : `"1180: Call to a possibly undefined method BackGround."`

Is there anyone to help me to solve what is wrong ?

**EDIT**

When I changed the code above lilke :

```
package{
    import flash .display.*;
    public class Arkaplan extends MovieClip{
        public function Arkaplan(){
            var myBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new backGround(500, 500));
            var myMovieclip:MovieClip=new MovieClip();

            myMovieclip.addChild(myBitmap);
            addChild(myMovieclip);
            trace("deneme 1-2");
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is solved but I dont know why it runs correctly know ? To be able to use Bitmap Do I have to add it as a child to movieClip ?

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use the word 'new' you are creating a new object. The word after new will be the name of a Class that Flash will try to locate. You must either have an external .as file that matches that name or have a library item set to 'export for ActionScript' with a Class name that matches that name.

You can access a library item's properties by right-clicking on it in the library and clicking 'properties'. With the 'advanced' option open, check the 'export for ActionScript' box and enter a Class name that matches the one you want to create.

Comment: thanks for valuable reply,however as you can see from the picture(http://prntscr.com/2pearu)    ,I've already done it.:( the type of backGround looks like bitMap. Could it be problem ? Should it always be movieClip?

Comment: Is the code above the sum total of the code in your game at the moment? Do you ever refer to background with a capital B? Because it looks like Flash is looking for a BackGround (capital B). If there is more code, you might be referencing BackGround somewhere. Another option is to run the game in debug mode (menu: Debug >> Debug Movie >> in Flash); that way, when the error occurs you'll be given a line number.

Comment: All the Code is given above, btw ,I edited my question

Comment: Just for clarity, it works because your library image is a BitmapData object, which is a required part of the Bitmap object. In your code, when you create a new Bitmap(..) you are passing the data of your library image as the BitmapData object. Additionally, because BitmapData does not inherit from DisplayObject (it inherits from Object) it can't, on its own, be displayed on screen.